# How to set position of a div always bottom another div

Tags: jquery, ajax, css

please help me review.

```
<.div id="parent"> Parent Div <./div> 
<br/>
<.div id="child">Child Div<./div>
```

Comment: why the dot in the `<.div>` ?

Comment: since `<div>`s are always [block level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) you need not to do anything unless it's having some specific css

Comment: Remove the dots, you'll get two magically stacked divs.

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid piece of code in your example.  should not have a dot on them, not on the opening or closing tag.

Remove the dot and give a style for #parent and #child in your CSS styles or add the style directly to your div element like this:

```
<div id="parent" style="border:2px solid black;display:inline;background:green;"> This is will be your parent div 
<div id="child" style="display:inline;background:blue;"> I am child of parents div </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.` inside the `<div>` and you will be surprised!

```
      <div id="parent"> Parent Div </div> 
      <div id="child">Child Div</div>
      also you dont need that <br/> anymore
```